# How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly

Tags: mysql, utf-8

One of the responses to [a question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198721/converting-a-word-document-into-usable-html-in-php) suggested that I should make sure my database can handle UTF-8 characters correctly. How I can do this with MySQL?

Comment: I really hope we get a comprehensive answer, covering various MySQL versions, incompatibilities, etc.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang -- MySQL 4.1 introduced `CHARACTER SETs`; 5.1.24 messed with the collation of German sharp-s (ß), which was rectified by adding another collation in 5.1.62 (arguably making things worse); 5.5.3 filled out utf8 with the new charset utf8mb4.

Comment: This question is quite same to this one.. Please look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: It's worth pointing out that most of these answers are just plain wrong.  Do not use `utf8`.  It only supports up to 3-byte characters.  The correct character set you should use in MySQL is `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**Update:**

Short answer - You should almost always be using the `utf8mb4` charset and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

To alter database:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

See:

- Aaron's comment on this answer [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly#comment28222734_202246)
- [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)
- Conversion guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html

**Original Answer:**

MySQL 4.1 and above has a default character set of UTF-8. You can verify this in your `my.cnf` file, remember to set **both** client and server (`default-character-set` and `character-set-server`).

If you have existing data that you wish to convert to UTF-8, dump your database, and import it back as UTF-8 making sure:

- use `SET NAMES utf8` before you query/insert into the database
- use `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` when creating new tables
- at this point your MySQL client and server should be in UTF-8 (see `my.cnf`). remember any languages you use (such as PHP) must be UTF-8 as well. Some versions of PHP will use their own MySQL client library, which may not be UTF-8 aware.

If you do want to migrate existing data remember to backup first! Lots of weird choping of data can happen when things don't go as planned!

Some resources:

- [complete UTF-8 migration](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html) (cdbaby.com)
- article on [UTF-8 readiness of php functions](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) (note some of this information is outdated)

Comment: My understanding is that `utf8` within MySQL only refers to a small subset of full Unicode. You should use `utf8mb4` instead to force full support.  See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4   "For a long time, I was using MySQL’s utf8 charset for databases, tables, and columns, *assuming* it mapped to the UTF-8 encoding described above."

Comment: MySQL has never had a default character set of UTF-8.  4.1 and 5.x up to the latest 5.7 all use `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci` for the default charset and collation.  See the "Server Character Set and Collation" page in the MySQL manual for confirmation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-server.html

Comment: *(Tim's comment has disappeared! But I think my response here might still be useful to some. Here it is: )* According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) the 5- and 6- bytes encodings have been removed. They were never actually used. Unicode never did define a range of characters that used the 5- or 6- byte encodings. I think [this email](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/Archives-Old/UML018/0330.html) explains it best

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yeah, I deleted it after I read that wikipedia article.  ;)

Comment: The most annoying aspect of utf8 in mysql is that 3 or 4 bytes have to be reserved for every possible character in your table.  So, `utf8mb4` means you can only save 1/4 the amount of regular English text as `latin1` if you're using the maximum row length.  I think that's why a lot of programs have given up and used BINARY if they have a lot of text to save. (wikipedia is an example)

Comment: @TimTisdall You need not worry `utf8mb4` taking extra storage when most text is ASCII. Although `char` strings are preallocated, `varchar` strings are not -- see the last few lines on [this documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).  For example, `char(10)` will be pessimistically reserve 40 bytes under utf8mb4, but `varchar(10)` will allocate bytes in keeping with the variable length encoding.

Comment: @Kevin I think you misread that.  I think the maximum row length is 64k.  You can only make a utf8mb4 field 1/4 of that because it had to reserve that amount of space.  So, even if it's ASCII you can only insert 16k characters.

Comment: @TimTisdall Oh, you're talking about upper bounds. Yes, those are lower. Fortunately, current versions of mysql will automatically upgrade from `varchar(n)` to the `text` data type if you attempt to alter a `varchar(n)` field to larger than the feasible byte size (while issuing a warning). An index will also have a lower worst-case upper bound, and that may present other problems.

Comment: The statement "... a default character set of UTF-8" is incorrect, according to MySQL's own documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html - it does not allow 4-byte characters at all.

Comment: Do not use `utf8`.  Use `utf8mb4`.  Converting a character set is already costly in terms of table locking and CPU time.  Don't bother with an inferior character set that doesn't support all of the characters.

Comment: Check if MySQL is currently using utf8[mb4] or latin1 using SHOW VARIABLES, e.g., `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Value LIKE 'latin1%';`. Here's another post on [how to configure utf8mb4 in my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24487309/664132).

Comment: - It will solve the” from now on “ created tables. NOT for EXIST tables. For them you need to do :
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Source - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/any-way-to-disable-charset-handshake-and-change-default-server-charset-in-managed-mysql

Comment: this keeps on changing, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci  is the way to go (as of 07/26/21)

Comment: Add mine to the voices that complain the instruction to use the collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci is not generally good advice.  That is no longer the default collation for utf8mb4 in modern versions of MySQL, and someone should have a specific reason for switching to it.  In fact, the linked answer about comparing _general_ci and _unicode_ci has been updated to recommend _not_ to use those collations any more.  This answer should be updated as well, indicating that you should almost always use utf8mb4, _and whatever the current default collation is for it._

Answer (score 48):

To make this 'permanent', in `my.cnf`:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
```

To check, go to the client and show some variables:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

Verify that they're all `utf8`, except `..._filesystem`, which should be `binary` and `..._dir`, that points somewhere in the MySQL installation.

Comment: It didn't work in my case but I created file my.cf in /etc with given content anyway. I used `create table my_name(field_name varchar(25) character set utf8);`

Comment: The "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';" command revealed me the problem with my connection. Thanks!

Comment: This is not correct. What MySQL calls `utf8` is not "full" UTF-8.

Comment: `set character_set_client=utf8;` to set a new value

Answer (score 33):

MySQL 4.1 and above has a default character set that it calls `utf8` but which is actually only a subset of UTF-8 (allows only three-byte characters and smaller).

Use `utf8mb4` as your charset if you want "full" UTF-8.

Comment: Definitely agree, this is the only correct answer. `utf8` doesn't include chars like emoticons. `utf8mb4` does. Check this for more info on how to update : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: @Basti -- Mostly correct (latin1 was the default until just recently), and not complete (does not discuss correctly inserting/selecting utf8-encoded data, nor displaying in html).

Comment: Respectfully, @RickJames, Basti said "so far" - I don't remember seeing your answer when I posted this.

Comment: Alas, there are about 5 distinctly different symptoms of utf8 problems, and about 4 things that programmers do wrong to cause trouble.  Most answers point out only _one_ thing that may need fixing.  The original question was broad one, so the answer needed all 4.  Perhaps Basti was familiar with _one_ symptom for which your one aspect was the solution.

Comment: Or, to look at another way, "handle UTF-8 characters correctly" can be read two ways...  You read it as needing utf8mb4.  I read it as not garbling the text on the way in/out of the database.  By your, and Basti's, interpretation, your answer is correct and complete.

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to pause a moment and give the MySQL team a really good, hard stare. o_o WTF were you guys thinking? Do you realize how much confusion you've sown by creating a codepage in your program called "utf8" that isn't actually UTF-8? Goddamn assholes. </rant>

Answer (score 23):

The short answer:  Use `utf8mb4` in 4 places:

- The bytes in your client are utf8, not latin1/cp1251/etc.
- `SET NAMES utf8mb4` or something equivalent when establishing the client's connection to MySQL
- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` on all tables/columns -- except columns that are strictly ascii/hex/country_code/zip_code/etc.
- `<meta charset charset=UTF-8>` if you are outputting to HTML.  (Yes the spelling is different here.)

[*More info*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#best_practice) ;
[*UTF8 all the way*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

The above links provide the "detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns". -- There is a space limit on this forum.

**Edit**

In addition to `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` containing "all" the world's characters, `COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is arguable the 'best all-around' collation to use.  (There are also Turkish, Spanish, etc, collations for those who want the nuances in those languages.)

Comment: My [_new link_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) on how to debug utf8 problems from the output you get.

Comment: Why unicode_520_ci is not the best all around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982378/62202

Comment: @Louis - And as I implied Spanish and Turkish (as well as Polish) users may not happy.  "Best all-around" tends to hurt everyone some.  MySQL 8.0 has an even newer "best" collation: [_utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html).  Alas, again L=Ł.

Answer (score 5):

The charset is a property of the database (default) and the table.
You can have a look (MySQL commands):

```
show create database foo; 
> CREATE DATABASE  `foo`.`foo` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */

show create table foo.bar;
> lots of stuff ending with
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=252 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In other words; it's quite easy to check your database charset or change it:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`.`bar` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4; /* was: utf8 */
```

Comment: This is not correct. What MySQL calls `utf8` is not "full" UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

I followed Javier's solution, but I added some different lines in my.cnf:

```
[myslqd]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

I found this idea here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html in the first/only user comment on the bottom of the page. He mentions that *skip-character-set-client-handshake* has some importance.

Comment: This unloved, zero-vote answer was the only thing that helped me!  So it gets my vote, that's for darn sure.  `skip-character-set-client-handshake` was the key.

Answer (score 3):

To change the character set encoding to UTF-8 for the database itself, type the following command at the mysql> prompt. USE `ALTER DATABASE`.. Replace DBNAME with the database name:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This is a duplicate of this question [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8/34986915#34986915)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `database collation` to `UTF-8`
then apply `table collation` to database default.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **collate utf8mb4 on mysql**, add the **attribute mysql_enable_utf8mb4** on DBI connection and do the sql command "**SET NAMES utf8mb4**" after connection to the mysql will make perl handle UTF-8 correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";

#use utf8;
#use open ':utf8';
#binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
#binmode STDIN , ":utf8";
#use encoding 'utf8';

our $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$servername;port=$port",$username,$password, {PrintWarn => 0, PrintError => 0, mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1}) || die;
$dbh->do("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is you can configure by MySql Settings. In My Answer may be something gone out of context but this is also know is help for you.
  *how to configure `Character Set` and `Collation`*.

> For applications that store data using the default MySQL character set
>   and collation (`latin1, latin1_swedish_ci`), no special configuration
>   should be needed. If applications require data storage using a
>   different character set or collation, you can configure character set
>   information several ways:

- *Specify character settings per database.* For example, applications
  that use one database might require `utf8`, whereas applications that
  use another database might require sjis.
- *Specify character settings at server startup.* This causes the server
  to use the given settings for all applications that do not make other
  arrangements.
- *Specify character settings at configuration time*, if you build MySQL
  from source. This causes the server to use the given settings for all
  applications, without having to specify them at server startup.

The examples shown here for your question to set utf8 character set , here also set collation for more helpful(`utf8_general_ci` collation`).

**Specify character settings per database**

```
  CREATE DATABASE new_db
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

**Specify character settings at server startup**

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

**Specify character settings at MySQL configuration time**

```
shell> cmake . -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 \
           -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci
```

*To see the values of the character set and collation system variables that apply to your connection, use these statements:*

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

This May be lengthy answer but there is all way, you can use. Hopeful my answer is helpful for you. for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html

Answer (score -2):

DATABASE CONNECTION TO UTF-8

```
$connect = mysql_connect('$localhost','$username','$password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);
mysql_select_db('$database_name','$connect') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: A number of other answers have already suggested this solution.  Please ensure you are providing a distinct contribution when answering old questions.

Answer (score -3):

`SET NAMES UTF8`

This is does the trick

Comment: While using `SET NAMES UTF8` (or `UTF8mb4`) is correct, you don't explain what it does (character set used for this connection). "This does the trick" sounds like it would solve the problem (make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly), but many MySQL databases are set to latin1 by default, so that wouldn't make it a proper solution. I would [change the default charset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24487309/664132) and the table charsets to utf8mb4. Really, this answer is rather incomplete, so I downvoted it.

Answer (score -3):

Set your database connection to UTF8:

```
  if($handle = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)){          
         //set to utf8 encoding
         mysql_set_charset('utf8',$handle);
  }
```

Comment: If running PHP, do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface.  Switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score -3):

Was able to find a solution. Ran the following as specified at http://technoguider.com/2015/05/utf8-set-up-in-mysql/

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
set collation_server = utf8_general_ci;
set default-character-set = utf8;
set init_connect = ’SET NAMES utf8′;
set character_set_server = utf8;
set character_set_client = utf8;
```

Comment: The last two lines are redundant, since the first one already includes those: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Also not a complete solution.  The columns need `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  `root` will not execute the all-important `init_connect`.