# MySQL won't store non-english characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Ok, I asked this question but the solutions didn't solve this problem.

Basically, my database stores ONLY English characters, even if its fields are set to UTF-8 unicode ci mode.

I tried storing Russian letters, it prints out weird Ñ�Ð¸ Ñ� characters.

Then I looked at PhpMyAdmin, those weird characters looked like this:

```
&ETH;&sup3;&ETH;&ordm;
```

HOWEVER, When I store something right from PhpMyAdmin, the Russian letters look fine. Yet, my page prints out ????? - question marks.

What is happening??? How to store and display different languages?

Comment: This has been asked over and over. My standard guess: you're not setting a *connection encoding*. Hard to suggest anything else without more details. See [How to handle Unicode in a web app](http://kunststube.net/frontback) for a complete checklist.

Answer (score 1):

First,  make sure you're working with the same charset in all the process, by this I mean, form, process, and db.

I'd recommend working with charset=utf-8 in the meta tag in the head of your HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Finally, don't forget to set your text fields to:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

I hope this works for you. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It's just a way of being sure that you're sending the right chars with the right charset to the db. That's all. By the way, this works for me, I'm not just coming with this code out of the blue. I work with spanish chars and I know how a pain in the arse can be working with special chars.

Comment: Also, when you're displaying your text, if it still doesn't come out right, just try to use htmlentities.

Comment: That "neat trick" is pretty *aweful*! In *older* PHP versions (< 5.4), this will encode UTF-8 encoded text into HTML entities, then decode those entities into Latin1. That means characters that can be represented in Latin1 will be decoded to Latin1, characters that cannot be will remain as HTML entities. You're then probably inserting that data into a database unknowingly using a `latin1` connection encoding, so it happens to work. This will break in PHP 5.4, since the default target charset changed to UTF-8 there. Read my comment on the OP's question. And -1 for such bad advice.

Comment: Take a good look at that line, when decoding it uses UTF-8, so no problem there. And I've used it since PHP 4.3 to the latest one, PHP 5.4 and had no issues. And finally, who made you the holder of truth, remember, in programming there's always multiple good and optimum solutions, not just one.

Comment: You are telling `htmlentities` that the *input* is in UTF-8. You are not telling `html_entity_decode` what to decode *to*, so it defaults to ISO-8859-1 (PHP < 5.4) or UTF-8 (5.4) respectively.

Comment: As for "holder of truth", well, good that programming is deterministic and can be tested: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1FOhGe

Answer (score 1):

This was my problem too and I finally found the way to solve it. I'm not a skilled coder but I write the answer here so that it may be helpful to those who just like me, didn't manage to solve their issue using other ways they have tried.

In my opinion, in general, you always have to make sure you've done these three things first:

**1-** Add this tag to each of your HTML sources that uses some text with a language other than English(add it between the opening and closing **head** tags):

```
<meta charset="utf8"/>
```

(As you see it's a tag without a closing pair)

**2-** Just after where you connect to your database (for example using a mysqli object called $conn), do this query too:

```
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

(At least this worked for my own language which is Farsi)

**3-** Set the collation of the tables you make to "utf8-general-ci" from scratch(...and I emphasize on this "*from scratch*". If you want to know the reason, read the rest of my answer below!):

Of course all these three things I've said above are important, but none of them helped myself when I was wrestling with this awkward disaster!  :(  So I was getting disappointed, but then as always this SO page showed up! :) 
 I read the brilliant article suggested by @deceze which is in the comments below the post, and saw these lines in it:

> The database server has a default character set, a database can have a default character set, a database table can have a default character set and finally the column has a character set setting. The rule is simple: if no explicit character set is specified for a column, the next higher default is used for it. The server, database and table defaults all have no influence whatsoever if the column has an explicit character set.

Actually, my silly problem was that I had made the table earlier(with a unicode other than the utf8) and **then** when trying to change its unicode to utf8, it didn't seem to work, because as the article says, even the collation of a table is separate from the collation of every single one of its fields, so when you change one, others tend to keep their default collations(the one you chose when you were making the table *from scratch*!) Finally, I went to structure tab in phpmyadmin, and changed the collation of those fields which were still using latin1 to utf8-general-ci too. (ci here stands for Case Insensitive)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Someone is already answered. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly/202246)

You need to change collation to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci".

Example database query

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```