# MySQL encoding for storing several languages

Tags: mysql, encoding

I need to store data in my MySQL db in 3 languages : French,Russian and Romanian. What encoding should i use for that? I used utf8_general_ci but i have problems with encoding non-latin letters with it. Thanks.

Comment: utf8 should be fine; please post details of the problems you are having.

Comment: UTF-8 is a perfect encoding for any language on Earth. Perhaps you're having collation issues (e.g., unexpected alphabetical order and the like). Can you please clarify?

Comment: For ex. Russian characters stored like strange cyrillic symbols, and Romanian and French special letters are transformed to smth like &copy; and different other things

Comment: Show the result of `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table

Comment: @VitKos: Make sure that your application and MySQL are talking to eachother in UTF-8 too (e.g. connection character set, encoding of strings in application, etc.)

Comment: MySQL will never generate HTML entities like `&copy;` by its own. I don't think it even has such feature. I'm pretty sure your problem is in your code (PHP or whatever).

Comment: @eggyal Yes,they are.. setting those properties when opening the connection

Comment: i think this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly

Comment: Thanks all for help, utf8_unicode_ci did the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8_unicode_ci was the right choice, also as was stated by @eggyal application and MySQL should comunicate using utf8