# In MYSQL, how do I set utf-8 as the default?

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

- I already created my database.
- I don't want to do this in my.cfg.

  I want to run an SQL query to set utf-8 as my default on this
  database.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `database`.`table` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; will alter a tables encoding. This was taken from MySql administrator. Not sure about a DB with 1 command.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start creating tables, it is no longer a single [ALTER DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) statement.  You need:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`.`bar` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATION utf8_general_ci
```

as already hinted in the comment.  This changes the collation of *all* columns in the table to the specified one.  However, it is also possible to control character set and collation also on column by column basis if desired.