# cannot post hebrew to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

I'm trying to add an Hebrew in my data base
From a simple form
I get letters like this

```
×©×œ×•×
```

Instead of

"שלום"

[link](http://pcksp5478.byethost7.com/index.php)

But I can not

What is the problem ,and whether it can be fixed?
Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: make sure that you are using UTF-8 charset end-to-end.

Answer (score 1):

Select utf-8 charset.

`mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php