# When to use utf8mb4 (bin, general_ci, unicode_520_ci)?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, utf8mb4

I'm confused about the MySQL Collations and its Encodings, People usualy uses one of these three collations:

1. **utf8mb_bin**
2. **utf8mb4_general_ci**
3. **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci**

What I don't understand is when to use each of these collations when needed, Like for example,

A table for names like this

```
[id - name]
```

It would only has names characters from different languages like **french, german, latin. . .**

Do I use for such a table the collation of `utf8mb_bin` or stick with `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`,

In other hand, A table for topics of a blog for example:

```
[id - title - subject]
```

Do I put all the columns collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` or use:

`utf8mb_bin` for `title`

`utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for `subject`

Since as I understood, the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` has some emotes in it that would be used in blogs subjects, Or do I just ignore everything and just use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` on all?

But overall, What is the point of using these different collations? And How does they affect my results in `SELECT` queries?

What I would like to know in berif is:

What collation to be used for each of:

1. names
2. titles
3. subjects
4. emails
5. bios
6. messages
7. usernames

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode -- which talks about `utf8`; however, `utf8mb4` and `utf8` have the same characteristics relative to this Question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're confusing encoding and collation.

The available characters are defined by the encoding (and only the encoding). Since UTF-8 is a Unicode-compatible encoding, you have *all* characters. The MySQL peculiarity is that its `utf8` encoding does not really implement UTF-8 but only a subset because it allocates 3 bytes per character and (as of today) some characters need 4 bytes. Thus `utf8mb4` was born.

Collation is a set of rules that tell you how `WHERE foo = bar` and `ORDER BY foo` work. You need to ask yourself: if I search for `internet`, should it match `Internet`? If you store French, German and Latin words you most likely don't want a binary collation. Ideally you want one with the exact rules of the language you'll be using but, since you're mixing languages, you'll have to opt for a generic collation. You can make an informed decision after reading [Difference between utf8mb4_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci collations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307146/difference-between-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-and-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci-collations-in-m).

Comment: So you mean that If I want accuracy in search then `Binary Collation` is the best to be used, Yet If It is for something I want it to be searchable and easy to reach as for `í` to be looked at as `i`, Then `unicode_ci` is better for that, Since it is case insenitve?

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. Binary means that `e` is totally different from `E` or `é` and the `é` character is different from `e` combined with `´`. Is that more accurate? It depends on what you need.

Comment: Then what is the different between these collation in usage exactly? Why would & **when** someone use `Binary` over `unicode_ci` and the vice-versa?

Comment: Yes e.g. you would use _bin on a column which holds email addresses. With a unique index on those email addresses you would assure that its possible to allow "müller@example.com" and "muller@example.com" or "rené@example.com" and "rene@example.com" as valid unique entries. And yes if you would like to implement a search it would be benefitting to use unicode_ci on a column which just will be search to return "rené" and "renè" if you just search "rene".