# utf8mb4_unicode_ci Selected in PhpMyAdmin but WordPress Tables using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci Collation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, collation

I have selected **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** Collation (since this was recommended to use instead of latin..) in PhpMyAdmin in both options, in **Server connection collation** under General settings and in Database under Operations Tab of PhpMyAdmin
but tables in that database which are of WordPress blog, are using **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** Collation (which can be seen on main window e.g by clicking on that database)

My Question is, is this any bad thing or does it have any negative effect that I have selected **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** but Database for WordPress blog is using **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** tables in Database. All of the tables in that database are using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.

1) Should I change options from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci in PhpMyAdmin (in both places as mentioned above)

2) Or it does not have any bad effect, I should leave it, as it is.

hoping to get answer for this query.
Thank You for reading.

Comment: collation will affect string comparison as far as i know. and its ok to have database collation and table collation different. however, it may result in [weird result](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28768) in case you are comparing two table with different collation. actually the suggestion to use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is when you are developing your own application, but since its wordpress.. we can do nothing much about it without changing the table ourselves - which may in turn broke wordpress..

Comment: It was recommend by WordPress Offfical Core Development team to use utf8mb4 source : https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/ ... so now should I leave this as it as?

Comment: Hi @Jack, the problem is your wordpress already using `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation which had [a bit of backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308117/4648586). while the article you shared is already 3 years old and refers to old wordpress 4.2. i believe it is better to leave as it is -- yours already 4.9 right? if yes, no need to worry.

Comment: yep, I have latest version of WP installed.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `CREATE TABLE ...`, the collation comes from:

- You can explicitly state the collation with the `CREATE`, or
- Defaulting to the database's collation (`CREATE DATABASE ...`)

Similarly, when declaring a column, you can be either explicit or default to the `TABLE's` settings.

I prefer to be explicit, not letting things default.

There is no harm when the database / table / column disagree on `CHARACTER SET` and/or `COLLATION`.

Until you get to MySQL 8.0, `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is the "best" collation.  (Best according to the Unicode standards committee.)