# insert ≠ (not equal to ) in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I run the following query in mysql

```
UPDATE `gamequestions` SET a2 = '≠' WHERE id = 564
```

It runs successfully but the '?' is inserted in a2 field in place of '≠'

The datatype of a2 is text and also tried with varchar

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have enable UTF8 for your database.

Comment: That's a special character. Use a Character Set that supports it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

Comment: If this is hardcoded into your PHP script, make sure the encoding for your text editor is set correctly to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *insert ≠ (not equal to ) in mysql field*

The goal in these conversions is always to decide on what `charset/collation` combination you want to use (`UTF8` being the best choice in almost all scenarios) then to convert all `tables/columns` in your database to use that charset. At that point you can set [DB_COLLATE](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) and DB_CHARSET` to the desired charset and collation to match.

***Note:***

> In most cases if a collation is not defined MySQL will assume the default collation for the CHARSET which is specified. For UTF8 the default is utf8_general_ci, which is usually the right choice.

***Changing the default charset of the database***

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

***Changing the default charset of individual tables***

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html***

Answer (score 2):

you need to change `Collation` to `UTF-8` to store special characters

Comment: Collation? There is no such thing as `UTF-8` collation. Are you sure you understand what `collation` is?

Answer (score 0):

You can add that option in the `/mysql/my.cnf`. In the [mysqld] section add ’’character-set-server=UTF8"; in the [client] section add `“default-character-set=UTF8”.`

You can find more information in these links:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-… http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-o…

If you need to conver existing data, you can execute:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on a mysql configuration, especially when it's possible to set on per-client basis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check following things

use set names utf8 before you query/insert into the database

using `Default CHARSET=utf8` when creating new tables