# Tables created by MySQL for Excel diacritics issue

Tags: mysql, excel, encoding, diacritics

I´m currently stuck on the following problem: Every time I create a table with MySQL for Excel, I do need to set the character encoding. I tried several ones from the list (including UTF-8) but none of them seems to be working properly - When I switch to MySQL server and look up the content of the table, the diacritics is not working properly and I´m getting strange characters instead of those I need to have.

Setup is the following: MySQL Server 6.0; Microsoft Excel 2010; MySQL plugin for Microsoft Excel. Language i use > Slovak.

How can I fix this issue, or, which encoding do I have to choose in order to fix it?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly especially the first comment to use `utf8mb4` encoding rather than the misleading `utf8` encoding.  Not sure if this is really a duplicate though, or if the issue is in the Excel plug-in.

Comment: @EricJ. - The plugin does not offer utf8mb4 but only utf8mb3 - I tried out but without success - issue stays the same.

Comment: I checked the charset of the table which is generated by the MySQL plugin - its latin1. By default, my databases come with latin1 charset too. So, theoretically, there shouldn´t be a problem, but practically the issue still remains the same.

Comment: Try as an experiment changing the DB encoding to utf-8 (perhaps try it on a test table).

Comment: @EricJ. - Tried out, doesn´t work. Funny thing - when I create the table manually + insert the data by myself - diacritics work. When I use the generated table form the plugin, diacritics doesn´t work also when the charsets match.