# Encoding Php to DB

Tags: php, mysql, web

I've got some problems with the codification on my db. 
Db and tables are set with utf8_general_ci, and all PHP web pages have some header with this encoding. 
From FORM I've to insert something, that is perfectly shown on web page, but on db figures like : Ã weÃ rewÃ fÃ dsÃ fewÃ

After db connection I've made some:

```
$connection->set_charset("utf8_general_ci");
```

Someone can help me with this?
Thank you everyone!!

Comment: I think you should follow the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly

Comment: I've seen it before ask question. This wasn't helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your insert query you can use 
utf8_encode($_POST['form_data']);
which encode special characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment...i've tried, result on db changed, but is like this:
ÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ asÃƒÂ fÃƒÂ eÃƒÂ eÃƒÂ¨ÃƒÂ¨

Comment: ohh..don't know much abt is. but i used collation utf8_unicode_ci