# Yii Framework 2.0 echo Japanese character from database

Tags: php, database, yii2

In my database user stores data in Japanese characters. When I query those data I did not get the data in Japanese characters but I got `å…¥åŠ›ãªã—` in stead. I don't know how to solve this. Below is my database configuration.

```
Yii::$app->components = [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database',
        'username' => '****',
        'password' => '****',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
];
```

If I remove `'charset' => 'utf8',` I got `???????` in stead of strange characters above or Japanese characters. I work with Yii framework 2 and with its ActiveRecord. Anyone knows any solutions?

Comment: Thanks you for your clue. I would like to vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that your database or your tables have the wrong charset/Collation. 
Check databases:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
```

Check tables:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

It's possible to convert existing data (from latin1 to utf8 for example) but not super-easy. I would say you'll have an much easier time just changing the default charset "[How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)" and create new database/tables rather than convert existing data.