# PHP mysqli_query into JSON excape special characters

Tags: php, mysql, json

All, I have the following code in php where I want to select data from mysql and put into json_encode. If it contains single quotes etc it fails.

```
// get the notes if any
$notes = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, notes FROM tc_ssa_notes WHERE ssa_id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ssa_id));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $notes[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

#en: send data packaged in json array
echo json_encode(array('notes' => $notes));
```

Output of `var_dump( $notes );`:

```
array(4) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(2) "26" ["item"] => string(55) "Are electrical panels covered when not being worked on?"
    } [1] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(2) "28" ["item"] => string(38) "Are extension cords in good condition?"
    } [2] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(2) "27" ["item"] => string(39) "B. Are (GFCI�S) in use (If Applicable)?"
    } [3] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(2) "29" ["item"] => string(53) "Is GFCI on the generator operational? (If applicable)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example output of `$notes`?

Comment: how does it fail? what error message do you get?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You mean an example of a row in notes?

Comment: B. Are (GFCI’S) in use (If Applicable)?

Comment: No error is generated. I am using ajax to send the ID to php and return data packed in JSON. Nothing is returned in the POST. If I turn on error checking nothing is generated. I used error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: please add `var_dump( $notes );` to your code, right before you try to echo the json and add this output to your answer

Comment: All, when I remove all special characters it works fine. I would like to leave the specials in place.

Comment: array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "26"
    ["item"]=>
    string(55) "Are electrical panels covered when not being worked on?"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["item"]=>
    string(38) "Are extension cords in good condition?"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["item"]=>
    string(39) "B. Are (GFCI�S) in use (If Applicable)?"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["item"]=>
    string(53) "Is GFCI on the generator operational? (If applicable)"
  }
}

Comment: All query should read $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, item FROM tc_ssa_notes WHERE ssa_id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ssa_id));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to your example output I guess you are writing to your database in the wrong encoding (at least for json_encode) maybe ISO-8859-1 or some other format.

[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) only works with UTF-8. From the docs:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

*A long term* solution would be to use UTF-8 as charset/collation in your database, here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202246/5297359) with some resources to this topic.

*A short term* (quickfix) could be to convert your string to UTF-8 ([utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)). If your string is ISO-8859-1 encoded, you can replace your while loop with this loop below:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $row["item"] = utf8_encode( $row["item"] );// added this line
    $notes[] = $row;
}
```

Additionaly for debugging json errors, you can use the build in functions below (depends on PHP version):

- [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)
- [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: The encoding was not UTF-8. I have changed and it works fine. Thanks