# MySQL field to store currencies name

Tags: mysql

I have a currencies table, which have a column called name, which is the currency name, for example:

```
PYG = Paraguayan guaraní­ --but it is store in table as Paraguayan guaranÃ­
STD = São Tomé and Príncipe dobra --but it is store in table as SÃ£o TomÃ© and PrÃ­ncipe dobra
```

What is Collation I can use to store these value?

Comment: "collation" is not about storing data, it's about comparing it.

Comment: seems like you store utf8 strings when your database expects latin1 (or similar) you should set up your database connection correctly. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly