# Best Method for Encoding/Decoding Multiple International Characters (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario: I created a plugin that scrapes meta data from news sites and stores in my D/B. However these pages could be in English, Russian, Chinese, Spanish and so on. I'm having one heck of a time scraping the data and storing in D/B generically. What is best method to grab the data from these pages, store to MySQL and then render on a single webpage? For example I may have 4 teasers featuring 4 different languages on one page. Not likely but technically it could happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to store the data in your database using the UTF-8 charset.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly) for more information, paying particular attention to the answer describing the `utf8mb4` option.

Later, when you retrieve this stored data and display it on a webpage, you should ensure that your HTML charset is set to UTF-8 via the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` header tag.

Comment: Thanks, I have not checked into utf8mb4 will do and test it out tonight and make update to stack.

Comment: Hey Nate! I just wanted to update. Everything was just fine but just as you mentioned I just needed to swap my cols from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb4_general_ci and it did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad this helped!  Cheers :)