# Arabic characters in python

Tags: python, sql, solr

I'm reading data from sql using my python script and upload it to Solr, but i'm facing an issue with the arabic letters,the script cannot upload the arabic letters properly, it shows me random characters and question marks in Solr(???????? ???).

This is a part of the script where i'm adding the return value from sql to the field in Solr:
["FIRSTNAME": ""+str(row[26].encode("windows-1256", 'strict'))+"",]

-FIRSTNAME is the field name in Solr 
-row[26] is the return value from sql (it has some arabic letters)

i tried windows-1256,cp720,utf-8... but got the same error

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: try the  utf-16 encoding

Comment: same error again

Comment: Do you use MySQL as BDMS?
You can use charset for Mysql like
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly