# Doctrine 2: getting strange caracters from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, pdo, doctrine

Im trying to show a text like this:

```
1ºA
```

stored in a MySQL table ('level').

After querying the table 'level' using this code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/list-level", name="list_level")
 */
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $levels = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Level')->findAll();
    var_dump($levels[0]->getName());
    die("fasf");
```

the `var_dump()` returns this:

[image]

Im using Symfony, so the information related to database connection is  cached in the file `var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer`. So I have opened it to check the value of `charset` parameter and I have found this:

```
protected function getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService()
{
    $a = new \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager($this);
    $a->addEventListener(array(0 => 'loadClassMetadata'), ${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners']) ? $this->services['doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners'] : $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners')) && false ?: '_'});

    return $this->services['doctrine.dbal.default_connection'] = ${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.dbal.connection_factory']) ? $this->services['doctrine.dbal.connection_factory'] : $this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory')) && false ?: '_'}->createConnection(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => NULL, 'dbname' => 'my_javiergarpe1979', 'user' => 'javiergarpe1979', 'password' => '*******', 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array(), 'defaultTableOptions' => array()), new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration(), $a, array());
}
```

As you can see on that function there is written this: `'charset' => 'UTF8'`, so.. **why am I not getting the correct caracters?**

Comment: Have you checked if it is formatted as UTF8?

Comment: @HarriedeLaat yes, look the end of my question.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is stored as `1ºA` in the table? @ziiweb

Comment: @SagarV yes, confirmed

Comment: Have you checked if the font you are using in the output has a definition for º? On top of that, what is the output if you query the database through console or i.e. phpmyadmin?

Comment: @HarriedeLaat it will covered in UTF-8

Comment: @ziiweb try change UTF-8 to `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: What is the character_set for the database and specific table? If it isn't stored as UTF-8 there you might run into problems

Comment: And please confirm that on the output for your page you have defined the charset as UTF-8 in the meta tags

Comment: Don't use `ISO-8859-1`, that will only cloud the issue.

Comment: How did you confirm that it was stored correctly?  The only sure way is to fetch the hex and get `31 C2BA 41`.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump('1ºA')`? Does it work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have to update `driverOptions` in your `var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer`:

```
protected function getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService()
{
    $a = new \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager($this);
    $a->addEventListener(array(0 => 'loadClassMetadata'), ${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners']) ? $this->services['doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners'] : $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_listeners.attach_entity_listeners')) && false ?: '_'});

    return $this->services['doctrine.dbal.default_connection'] = ${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.dbal.connection_factory']) ? $this->services['doctrine.dbal.connection_factory'] : $this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory')) && false ?: '_'}->createConnection(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => NULL, 'dbname' => 'my_javiergarpe1979', 'user' => 'javiergarpe1979', 'password' => '*******', 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array('1002'=> "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'"), 'defaultTableOptions' => array()), new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration(), $a, array());
}
```

Set `'driverOptions' => array('1002'=> "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'")` instead of `'driverOptions' => array()`.

Answer (score 2):

*Probably* it is a browser problem in not having `<meta charset=UTF-8>` in the header.

See "black diamonds" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

`º` is the "MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR".

If you `SELECT HEX(...)` from the table, you should see `C2BA` for that character.  Or `31C2BA41` for `1ºA`.  If so, then it was correctly stored as `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

Case 1 (original bytes were not UTF-8):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8. Fix this.
- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` was not utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET` utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Case 2 (original bytes were UTF-8):

- The connection (or `SET NAMES`) for the `SELECT` was not utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you have other issues.

Comment: what exactly should I execute? I have tried `SELECT HEX('C2BA')` and I get `43324241`. Is that a correct result?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` as suggested in my link.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple points where this could have gone wrong.

1. Check the character set which you are using on the database. Also check the table because those can have their own encoding.
   See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/202246/2232127
2. Check the character set which you are using for the connection *(you have set this already)*
3. Check the character set in which the page is displayed. You can set this via a this meta tag: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` tag.
4. You have to use a font that supports this character. Most fonts shouldn't show the `<?>` character but instead may show something similar to `°` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Check the table's character set in database. May be its not UTF-8.