# php and mysql accent issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php, i made a php user interface with input fields that formulates, prints and execute a query showing the database reply or error.

It usually works fine but when i make a query with accented fields like in

```
"INSERT INTO `Nave` (`Targa`, `Nazionalità`, `Nome`) VALUES('0', 'italia', 'nave0');"
```

php successfully creates the query, prints and executes it without any further modifications but it fails saying "Unknown column 'Nazionalità' in 'field list'"
but if i copy/paste the same exact query printed by php into phpmyadmin it works (so obiouvsly the column 'Nazionalità' does exist) what is happening?

Notice that if the php generated query has no fields with accent it works even in php.
**Notice also that individually neither my php nor mysql have any issues dealing with accent.** so it's NOT a duplicate of [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly) because that's a mysql individual issues, my database works fine.

EDIT: All the answers so far explained how to fix the database, but the **database does works fine!** 
I do not know how to make it understand that, read more about the question guys...
But the second duplicate suggestion was quite right and there i found my solution which I copy here for convenience of those who will visit this page having the same problem: "$mysqli->set_charset('put here the same charset used in your db');" OR "mysqli_set_charset($link, 'charset');"
Thank for your help.

Comment: Check your table column `Nazionalità` or `Nazionalita`

Comment: There is special character inside this word `Nazionalità` is `à` I don't mysql support this

Comment: what is the db's/table collation? you may need to pass UTF-8 to the connection first also

Comment: Do not use non ASCII char as column or table names

Comment: Check your DB schema for the correct column name, or maybe page character (UTF-8) encoding?

Comment: @Mr.Developer it does support it.

Comment: did you leave the question? *partite?* you received comments asking for clarification but have not seen any of them responded to.

Comment: my database works fine and have a charset that support accent.
i replied editing my question and in the second duplicate suggestion i got my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change your character set of database to UTF-8 by following MySQL query

```
ALTER TABLE Nave CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```