# PHP - Convert HTML Symbol to HTML Entity

Tags: php, encoding, html-entities, decoding

```
$html_str = "Random Text&#8482; First Second Third";

echo $str = html_entity_decode($html_str);
```

outputs: Random Text™ First Second Third

now how do I convert $str to $html_str?

Comment: Note that you do not need to run `$html_str` through `html_entity_decode()` to output `Random Text™ First Second Third` - it will display just fine without any decoding.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie you are absolutely right. Lets say, I want to save "Random Text™ First Second Third" in my mysql db like this:- "Random Text&#8482; First Second Third". How would I do that?

Comment: Well... i tested now, and the closest I got was using `htmlentities(string goes here)`- however, it stores the character as `&trade;`, not `&#8482;`, which might be a problem, or not, depending.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie that would be fine. When I try it, my db stores ™ as â¢ which is not even close. I am starting to think my mysql settings aren't right. I set the db coalition to utf8-bin btw.

Comment: Everything needs to be UTF 8. The db, the files, etc. Also, I don't think utf8-bin is the right choice. On my cell phone right now, which limits things a bit, bit you might find some tips/answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/202205/1561164

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation:
"html_entity_decode() is the opposite of htmlentities()..."
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

"htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities"
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

You want to use `htmlentities`

`$html_str = htmlentities($str);`

Comment: I tried that but it outputs the original string: Random Text™ First Second Third

Comment: Of course it does. The OUTPUT doesn't change, but how the string is stored might.