# SQL fails with a non-ascii char

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've got a SQL operation with the word "şalom" which contains a non-ASCII character. 
And the statement ( which I posted below ) runs totally fine:

```
UPDATE `myTable1` SET `description`='The topic for this learning plan starts with the \"ÅŸ\" ( sh ) letter which is a non-ASCII char. ', `topic`='ÅŸalom'' WHERE `RecID` = '1308'"
```

however, right after this statement, I have to run another one to put the word "şalom" in another table but that one FAILS. The reported error is follows:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable2` (`TOPIC_Name`, `TOPIC_AddedOn`) VALUES ('[Åÿalom]', '2018-04-12').
```

LAST SQL ERROR:

```
HY000, 1366, Incorrect string value: '\xC5\xFFalom...' for column 'Topic_Name' at row 1
```

We've checked the table structures and the field structures and saw that they are identical and designed to accept utf-8.

We cannot figure out why one statement passes but the other one chokes. Any ideas?

Comment: Erm... 0xc5 0xff isn't valid UTF-8...

Comment: I realize that but if you check the "insert into", i'm using "[Åÿalom]" in the statement. I have no idea where & how I end up with "\xC5\xFFalom". I do not have control over that. And that IS the the problem, I think.

Comment: Did you tell the connection which charset you want to use?

Comment: I do not think I did but if there was something up with that wouldn't the "update" statement which runs in the earlier operation also fail?

Comment: You may need to `SET NAMES UTF8` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly

Comment: Also, I just run the same statement in phpmyadmin against that database as follows: INSERT INTO `sc_topics` (`TOPIC_Name`, `TOPIC_AddedOn`) VALUES ('şalom]', '2018-04-12')   And it just went thru. It's even more puzzling now. why is it in PHP EZ-SQL fails at this?

Answer (score 0):

`ÅŸ` is Mojibake for `ş`.  When treated as latin1, `ÅŸ` is hex C5FF.  See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of "Best practice" and "Mojibake".