# displaying Japanese characters with php from database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

PHPMyAdmin is displaying Japanese characters perfectly with COLLATION =: utf8mb4_unicode_ci but it just displays ???? in the browser.

I am using the correct UTF code in the HTML headers like:

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Here are the PHP code snippets:

```
`<?php
//Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'quizzer';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if($mysqli->connect_error){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

//Set question number
$number = (int) $_GET['n'];

/*
*   Get total questions
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`";
//Get result
$results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$total = $results->num_rows;

/*
*   Get Question
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`
            WHERE question_number = $number";
//Get result
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$question = $result->fetch_assoc();

/*
*   Get Choices
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM `choices`
            WHERE question_number = $number";
//Get results
$choices = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);


<?php $question['question_number']; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?>

<?php echo $question['text']; ?>

<?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()): ?>

    <?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><?php echo $row['text']; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>`
```

Comment: This answer will help you, just use *utf8mb4* instead of *utf8*  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/202246/5527461

Comment: how do I add this:       mysqli_set_charset('utf8')    to this:    $mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

Answer (score 0):

(continuing from comment section)
After connecting to mysql :-

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

This is will set your default charset to "utfmb4", so every query after this will maintain this charset.

To make this 'permanent', in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Its working perfectly now that I added: mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");


$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

Answer (score 0):

Just add mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

```html
$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
```