# MySQL phpMyAdmin Invalid utf8mb4 character string

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

I am unable to make basic encoding work with MySQL and phpMyAdmin. I want to use simple french characters (such as é and è) in my data. If I run an UPDATE, the characters insert correctly. But not when I import the script...

Below is the script I import on phpMyAdmin :

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE Proprietaire (
    idProprietaire int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nomProprietaire varchar(255)
    )DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
;

INSERT INTO Proprietaire (nomProprietaire) VALUES
('Léanne'),
('Fabrice'),
('Pedro')
;
```

The 2 errors I am getting when importing :

```
Warning: #1300 Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'E9616E'
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE9anne' for column 'nomProprietaire' at row 1
```

When importing the script on phpMyAdmin, the only choice close to utf8mb4 is utf8

[image]

The table AND the database are also in a similar encoding

[image]

But the data is stripped..

[image]

What I tried to do

- Add COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci to the colum that needs special characters -> Did nothing
- Modify into DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 and DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1. Latin1 replaces the accents with ? while utf8 simply cuts the word
- Google 'E9616E', found absolutely nothing??
- ALTER DATABASE mydbname CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci; -> Did nothing
- Links I checked : [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly), [Characters appear as question marks using MySQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/characters-appear-as-question-marks-using-mysql-204051027.html), [MySQL silently replaces UTF chars with literal question marks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/mysql-silently-replaces-utf-chars-with-literal-question-marks), [Show and change MySQL default character set](https://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E9 is the latin1 encoding for e-acute.  You have latin1 somewhere.  For utf8mb4, it needs to be C3A9.

Apparently phpmyadmin is configured for latin1, since typing

```
INSERT INTO Proprietaire (nomProprietaire) VALUES
('Léanne'), ...
```

gives you the E9.

The `character_set_*` being set to `utf8mb4` declare that the client (phpmyadmin) used UTF-8 encoding, but apparently it does not.

Comment: I had previously tried a combination of utf8 and latin1 without luck. Following your comment, I replaced SET NAMES utf8mb4; with SET NAMES latin1; , changed my database's default encoding and removed the DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4. It worked!

Comment: I think `SET NAMES latin1` is what made it work; the rest probably does not matter.