# Are there any alternatives for MySQL's regex_replace feature pre-8.0 that doesn't require UDFs?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm attempting to search records by passing in a squashed version of a column - If I pass in "Martin" I would expect the matching "M-@art*in" would be returned. This is something that REGEX_REPLACE seems to handle well in MySQL 8.0+ and I've seen many recommendations for User Defined Functions (UDFs) that can do the same job pre-8.0. My supervisor doesn't want to rely on UDFs, and so I am wondering if there are any other options?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to search, or change values? You could use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to search. But no, there's no equivalent pre-8.0 to the REGEXP_REPLACE() function. Only REPLACE() which does not support regular expressions.

Comment: That said, you should be thinking about upgrading to MySQL 8.0 anyway, because MySQL 5.7 is due to reach its end of life in October 2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a specific set of characters allowed, you could do e.g. `replace(replace(replace('M-@art*in','-',''),'@',''),'*','')`

If not, you can have a somewhat cumbersome query that looks at each character individually and tests if it should be included in a group_concat that reassembles them:

```
select id, group_concat(substr(bar,i,substr(bar,i,1) regexp '[a-z]') order by i separator '') clean_bar
from (select 1 i union select 2 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) i
join foo on i <= length(bar)
group by foo.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ff71ce9ca20ad3bb381f4d6a54dd3cac)

But you'd probably want to run that on the data and store the squashed version in a separate column if you are trying to search on it.

Note that mysql 5.7 will no longer be supported in 14 months; do plan to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql), extract the column and update them.

Or, come to think of it, set your [collation to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)