# fgetcsv inserting charactor like ?????? into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, fgetcsv

I am making a little php application with fgetcsv for inserting multiple record into mysql database. It works fine with english charactor. But when I trying to add foreign language like bengali or hindi it inserts ????? into mysql database.

Here my mysql database table structure

[image]

Here a result for foreign language character

[image]

Here my application code

```
<?php

    // Use PDO to connect to the DB
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=phpcsv_db;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $handle = fopen('data.csv', "r");

    for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++) {
        // The query uses placeholders for data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO phpcsv
                    (name,email,phone) 
                VALUES
                    (:name,:email,:phone)";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        // The data is bound to the placeholders
        $sth->bindParam(':name', $data[0]);
        $sth->bindParam(':email', $data[1]);
        $sth->bindParam(':phone', $data[2]);

        // The row is actually inserted here
        $sth->execute();
        $sth->closeCursor();
    }
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);

fclose($handle);
```

Here the [data csv file](http://url.skjoy.info/1njcjw) I am using and some foreign character here শ্যামল অসিম কার্তিক

Any suggestion or solution will highly appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Verify that your CSV file in encoded in UTF-8 like your database table. For instance, I opened it in Notepad++ and it also shows ?????? for me [link](https://i.imgur.com/8S0rIDG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

Comment: Obviously, it's a Character Set problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that. Notepad++ gives me same result. It will be best if we solve this issue programmly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Word document into usable HTML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198721/converting-a-word-document-into-usable-html-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets() get file all string in a variable, then use  `mb_convert_encoding()` to convert encoding, then `str_getcsv(`) convert string to array.

```
if (($handle = fopen("books.csv", "r")) === FALSE)
    throw new Exception("Couldn't open books.csv");

$data = "";

// get file all strin in data
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $data .= fgets($handle, 5000);
}

// convert encoding
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "auto");

// str_getcsv
$array = str_getcsv($data);
```

the from array you can save it in db.

Comment: This. We process multiple CSV's and encoding is the worst, we also need to ensure the data is parsed as UTF-8 for other purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but couldn't figure it out. Can you please change my code with your code?

Comment: hmm... now the `$array` variable contains all the data from the csv file properly encoded. verify it by `var_dump($array);` . then loop through that array and try to insert it in to database,

Comment: var_dump($array) return like this image http://prntscr.com/i4rkvv